# Организация проекта с зависимостями от библиотек

Tags: c++, библиотеки, кроссплатформенность

Вопрос возможно немного размытый. Поэтому попытаюсь его описать подробнее и разбить на вопросы по мельче.

Вот, например, я хочу написать программу, которой потребуется несколько библиотек. Как лучше всего эти библиотеки добавить в проект?

Некоторых библиотек нет в репозитории и их приходится качать с сайта куда-то (?) распаковывать, как-то (?) добавлять инклуды и исходный код этих библиотек.

В каких случая создавать `.so/.dll` файлы, а в каких случаях можно сразу сразу собирать один исполняемый файл из всех `.cpp`?

Хочется также сделать программу кроссплатформенной и если я на *Linux* поставил библиотеку из репозитория, то как быть на других платформах.

Или для этих вопросов нет какого-то правильного, универсального способа и делай как получится?

Пока что лучим решением для себя вижу только `cmake`.

Было бы круто найти инструмент, который бы мог сам подгружать необходимые библиотеки :) как в `npm` или `gradle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QtCreator + qmake.

Можно компилировать библиотеки сразу под разные компиляторы или разные версии одного компилятора, к примеру msvc2010, msvc2013, msvc2015.
Далее для библиотеки создается pri файл, в котором указывается путь к хидерам, и в зависимости от используемого компилятора и версии компилятора подключаются нужные lib/so файлы.

В итоге, когда в проекте мы хотим подключить библиотеку, нам всего-ли нужно указать путь к pri файлу.

Пример pri файла:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/include

!isEmpty(OUT_DIR) {
    LIBS += -L$${OUT_DIR}
} else {
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/bin/$${QT_VERSION}
}

LIBNAME = DatabaseHelper2

LIBS += -l$${LIBNAME}$${STATIC_POSTFIX}$${MYCOMPILER_POSTFIX}$${DEBUG_POSTFIX}
```

Пример подключения в проект:

```
include(D:/git_projects/DatabaseHelper2/DatabaseHelper2.pri)
```

И создать какой-то common.pri, где вычисляем переменные:

```
compileName=$$basename(QMAKESPEC)

equals(compileName, win32-msvc2013) {
    MYCOMPILER_POSTFIX = _vc12
}

equals(compileName, win32-msvc2010) {
    MYCOMPILER_POSTFIX = _vc10
}

equals(compileName, win32-msvc2015) {
    MYCOMPILER_POSTFIX = _vc14
}

DEBUG_POSTFIX =
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    DEBUG_POSTFIX = _d
}

STATIC_POSTFIX =
contains(DEFINES, STATIC) {
   STATIC_POSTFIX = _static
}
```

И подключать его самым первым:

```
include(D:/git_projects/common.pri)
include(D:/git_projects/DatabaseHelper2/DatabaseHelper2.pri)
```